# JavaScript pattern: "copy" ClassA properties to ClassB

Tags: javascript, class, design-patterns, prototype, this

seen this JavaScript pattern in some large projects, which "copies" or "implements" ClassA's properties to ClassB, but couldn't figure out what is the purpose of calling ClassA's empty constructor inside ClassB's constructor using ".call()" while passing the ClassB instance as "this" binding?

```
var ClassA = function() {
    //this function is totally empty
};

ClassA.prototype = {
    jump: function() {...some code...},
    dance: function() {
        if (this.canDance) {
            alert("dance");
        }
    }
};

ClassA.implementOn = function(targetClassOrObject) {
    for ( var prop in ClassA.prototype ) {      
        targetClassOrObject[ prop ] = ClassA.prototype[ prop ];
    }
};

var ClassB = function() {
    this.canDance = true;
    ClassA.call(this);          // <------------What's the purpose of this line?
};

ClassA.implementOn(ClassB.prototype);

var instanceOfB = new ClassB();
instanceOfB.dance();
```

Comment: What does `ClassB` do if you remove it?

Comment: If you mean removing the `ClassA.call(this);` line in the `ClassB` constructor, it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: It doesn't make any difference *only because* the `ClassA` constructor is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `ClassA` constructor is empty, there's no big surprise here -- `call`ing `ClassA`'s empty constructor does absolutely nothing.

The moment you decide you want `ClassA`'s constructor to be non-empty, however, you'll see that line now has a tremendously important effect: constructing a `ClassB` object also invokes the `ClassA`-specific constructor behaviors in the context of newly-constructed `ClassB` object, which is what you'd expect if `ClassB` is a logical "subclass" of `ClassA`.

(Of course, JavaScript doesn't have proper "subclasses", but this is obviously an attempt to implement class-based behavior in the language.)

Answer (score 1):

> purpose of calling ClassA's empty constructor inside ClassB's constructor using ".call()"

To have the script still working when `ClassA` will not be empty. Of course, currently it does nothing, but that might change in future. So it is good practise to implement the full inheritance pattern, making it easier to change the code later without introducing bugs.

Once `ClassA` changes to implement custom instance-specific properties - which are set up in the constructor, you want to have them on `ClassB` instances as well. Therefore, you invoke the `ClassA` constructor on `ClassB` instances as well during their initialisation.

Answer (score 1):

If the `ClassA` constructor is empty (like in your example code), then yeah, it does nothing.

The reason you see this pattern though, is for the times when it's not. It's analogous to a `super` call in a class-based OO language.

If you have to do some work in the `ClassA` constructor to get an object that's in a correct state, it's likely you'll want to do the same work in a "subclass". Just copying the prototype's properties may not be enough.

Answer (score 0):

With `.call`, you can change the value of `this` in the called method to the argument you specify.  `ClassA.call(this)` calls the `ClassA` constructor with `ClassB` as the context.  This allows you to use the properties of `ClassB` in `ClassA` methods.  The methods are all copied to `ClassB` via `ClassA.implementOn`.

You will notice that `(new ClassA()).dance()` does nothing, but `(new ClassB()).dance()` alerts `"dance"` because `this.canDance` is true.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5v7xh/

Comment: Remove the `ClassA.call` from your example and see how `dance()` still works for `ClassB` instances.